# How to generate circular matrix?

Tags: c++, c, matrix

I want to generate a circular matrix in C or C++.

How can I generate the matrix below, for n = 3?

```
1 2 3
8 9 4
7 6 5
```

Comment: Please decide whether you are talking about `C` or `C++` as the solution will be very different in each case. (And you might also want to mention whether this is homework or not - it looks strangely familiar...)

Comment: @Paul: well the difficult part here is how to generate the coordinates for the index smartly, now how to store them in a 2D matrix. So just in this case, the language really is more or less irrelevant.

Comment: This smells like `homework`...

Comment: @Konrad: true, but if the creation of the 2D matrix itself will most be very different in each case, and it the OP really needs a specific C or C++ implementation then there may be some wasted time and effort in the resulting *to and fro*.

Comment: @Hiren Dabhi, you'll need to say what you've done and whether the question is about storage or population the matrix.

Comment: @xbonez: ["The homework tag...is now discouraged,"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10812) but, @Hiren, please (as always) follow [general guidelines](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints): state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In a "circular" matrix, the "middle" of it is circular too,
except that it doesn't start with 1.
So run round the perimeter and recurse.

```
void    cmat_step( int** M, int a, int i, int j, int dim)
{    
int    k;
    /* fill perimeter */
    for( k=0; k<dim; ++k)        M[i][j+k]       = a++;
    for( k=1; k<dim; ++k)        M[i+k][j+dim-1] = a++;
    for( k=dim-2; k>=0; --k)     M[i+dim-1][j+k] = a++;
    for( k=dim-2; k>=1; --k)     M[i+k][j]       = a++;
    if ( dim >=2)    
    {    /* fill middle */
        cmat_step( M, a, i+1,  j+1, dim-2);
    }
}
void    cmat( int** M, int dim)    {    cmat_step( M, 1, 0, 0, dim);    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I did it some times ago...

Pseudocode:

```
min_x = 0;
min_y = 0;
max_x = X;
max_y = Y;

while(!all_fields_filled){

  // move right  -------------------------
  for(i = min_x; i <= max_x; i++){
    array[min_y][i] = fields_number;
    fields_number++;
  }

  min_y++

  // it is important to check that condition after each for
  // (our total field number could be not divided by 4)
  if(filled_fields == fields_amount) break;
  // edn "move right" procedure -----------


  // ETC. for move DOWN, next LEFT and UP
  // remember to increase min_x/min_y and decrease max_y/max_y

}
```

Comment: +1 for only giving peudocode for a rather obvious hw question.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @Rin's answer, you could consider storing the matrix in linear order, and then re-mapping indices when accessing it.  If you're in C++, you can encapsulate this re-mapping via the accessor functions, e.g.:

```
class WierdMatrix
{
public:
    ...

    int get(int x, int y) const
    {
        /* Mapping goes here */
        return M_[x_mapped][y_mapped];
    }
private:
    int M_[3][3];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This question asked in Microsoft written test.
Hence considering to give full code.

Below code works for any number of rows and any number of columns given at runtime.
No need of hardcoding the dimensions.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Prints matrix in Spiral fashion.
void printSpiral(const int& numRows, int& numCols)
{
    int **v = new int*[numRows]; //Allocation for rows
    for(int i = 0; i< numRows; i++)   //Allocation for columns
    {
        v[i] = new int[numCols];
    }
    int curRow = 0, curCol = -1; //for storing current position while moving.
     //Below variables are for remembering boundaries
     //That is already traversed row/column
     int minRowLimit = -1, maxRowLimit = numRows;
     int minColLimit = -1, maxColLimit = numCols;

    int num = 1; //Start filling from 1
     //Total number of elements to be filled
    int totalElements = numRows * numCols; 
    while(1)
    {
        while(curCol < maxColLimit-1)  //Move right
        {
            ++curCol;
            v[curRow][curCol] = num;
            num++;
        }
        if(num > totalElements) break; //Filling completed.
        minRowLimit++;

        while(curRow < maxRowLimit-1) //Move down
        {
            ++curRow;
            v[curRow][curCol] = num;
            num++;
        }
        if(num > totalElements) break; //Filling completed.
        maxColLimit--;

        while(curCol > minColLimit+1)     //Move left
        {
            --curCol;
            v[curRow][curCol] = num;
            num++;
        }
        if(num > totalElements) break; //Filling completed.
        maxRowLimit--;

        while(curRow > minRowLimit+1)  //Move up
        {
            --curRow;
            v[curRow][curCol] = num;
            num++;
        }
        if(num > totalElements) break; //Filling completed.
        minColLimit++;
    }
     //Print the matrix for verification.
    for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < numCols; j++)
        {
            cout<<v[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

     //Clean up.
    for(int i = 0; i<numRows; i++)
    {
        delete []v[i];
    }
    delete []v;
}

int main()
{
     //Enter rows and columns according to your choice 
     //regarding matrix dimensions.
    int nRows, nCols;
    cout<<"Enter number of rows"<<endl;
    cin>>nRows;
    cout<<"Enter number of cols"<<endl;
    cin>>nCols;
    printSpiral(nRows, nCols);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what bearing the presence of this question on a Microsoft written test has on your decision to provide full code. Generally, we learn best if we're not immediately presented with a solution. Thanks for providing some explanation in the code, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define N 3

int coords[N*N];

void printn() {
  int i,j;
  for ( i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ ) {
    for ( j = 0 ; j < N ; j++) {
      printf("%2d ",coords[i*N+j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

void gennum(int n,int ox,int oy,int lx) {
  int i,j,k,l;
  for ( j = ox; j < n ;j++) {
    coords[ (oy*N)+j ]=  j-ox + lx;
  }

  for ( i = oy+1; i < n ;i++) {
    coords[ (i*N) + n-1 ] = (i-1) -(oy) + (j-ox) + lx;
  }

  for ( l = n-2 ; l >=ox ;l--) {
    coords[ (n-1)*N + l ] = (n-l-2)+ (i-1) -(oy) + (j-ox)  + lx ;
  }

  for ( k = n-2; k >= oy+1 ;k--) {
    coords[ (k*N)+ox ] = (n-k-2)+(n-l-2)+ (i-1) -(oy) + (j-ox) + lx ;
  }
  if ( n > 2 ) {
    gennum(n-1,ox+1,oy+1,(n-k-2)+(n-l-2)+ (i-1) -(oy) + (j-ox) + lx); 
  }
}

int main() {
  memset(coords,0,N*N*sizeof(int));
  gennum(N,0,0,1);
  printn();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Select a code block and then use ctrl-k or the 101 button to indent it.

Comment: From the [homework question guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812) (meta): "Try to provide explanation that will lead the asker in the correct direction...It's usually better not to provide a complete code sample if you believe it would not help the student, using your best judgment." Your judgment's your own, but it generally doesn't help *understanding* to just write the full code.

Comment: In addition to @Jefromi 's remark, and especially when there is no explanation given, this would be a bad answer even for a non-homework question.

Answer (score 0):

First make your matrix empty.  In my example, I use an std::map on an std::pair, but you could also use a 2-dimensional array.  I use std::map because it's easier to see when an element is missing.

```
typedef std::pair<int,int> Coordinate;
typedef std::map<Coordinate,int> Matrix;
```

Then make a collection that contains the different directions in which you want to move.
If first want to move to the right, it means incrementing X by 1, and leaving Y as it is.  Then we move down, meaning incrementing Y by 1 and leaving X.

```
typedef std::vector<Coordinate> Moves;
Moves moves;
moves.push_back(std::make_pair(1,0));
moves.push_back(std::make_pair(0,1));
moves.push_back(std::make_pair(-1,0));
moves.push_back(std::make_pair(0,-1));
```

Initialize your starting coordinate and them move until you reach a 'boundary'.  A boundary is either the border or a cell that has already been filled in.

```
Coordinate currentPosition = std::make_pair(0,0);
int currentValue = 1;
int currentMovePosition = 0;
```

Then in a loop (but I leave this as an excercise for you to write this out :-)) simply fill in the matrix:

```
matrix[currentPosition] = currentValue;
++currentValue;
```

and move to the next position;

```
Coordinate nextPosition = currentPosition;
nextPosition.first += moves[currentMovePosition].first;
nextPosition.second += moves[currentMovePosition].second;
```

check the nextPosition to see if you are outside your matrix (nextPosition.first/second < 0 or >= size of matrix).

If you are still within the matrix use std::find in the map to see if this entry has already been filled in:

```
if (matrix.find(nextPosition)!=matrix.end()) /* valid position */
```

If you bump against the boundaries of the matrix or you bump into an entry that has already been filled in, take the current position again, increment currentMovePosition to change the direction and try again.
Be sure to wrap currentMovePosition around if you change direction.

```
currentMovePosition = (currentMovePosition + 1) % 4;
```

Continue doing this until the matrix is completely filled.

To determine whether the matrix is completely filled, you can check whether all 4 directions all move to elements that are already filled, but an easier approach is to simply count the number of filled cells and stop if it equals the size*size of the matrix.